# How to compare UIImages in arrays?

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, uiimage

I'm making an application where it would be nice to be able to compare values inside one array/set.

Let's say I have constants and an array like this:

```
let blueImage = UIImage(named: "blue")
let redImage = UIImage(named: "red")

button.setImage(blueImage, forState: .Normal)
button2.setImage(redImage, forState: .Normal)
button3.setImage(blueImage, forState: .Normal)

var imageArray:Array<UIImage> = [button.currentImage, button2.currentImage, button3.currentImage]
```

Is it then possible to check/compare the values in my array and replace the red images with the blue ones.

More specifically is there a way I can check if 2/3 of the images in the array contains a specific image(`blueImage`), and then replace the last value(`redImage`) with (`blueImage`) so that all has the same picture.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you could filter the array with something along these lines:

```
let filteredArray = filter(imageArray) { $0 == blueImage }
```

and then run a count.

You could also iterate over your array:

```
let countBlue = 0

for i in 0..<imageArray.count {

    if imageArray[i] == blueImage {
        countBlue ++
    }
}
```

To replace an element:

```
imageArray[2] = blueImage
```

Comment: @Polis I'm unsure what `{ $0 == blueImage }` does, can you please explain that to me?